# Flipping a sprite with xScale in SpriteKit in iOS 8 doesn't flip the SKPhysicsBody

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, sprite-kit

I have a setup where there is an empty `SKSpriteNode` ("Player") that has N number of `SKSpriteNode`s as childs (body parts, such as "Arm"). Every child has an `SKPhysicsBody` created like this:

```
sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: sprite.texture, size: sprite.texture!.size())
```

When I try to flip the whole sprite ("Player) with

```
self.xScale = -1
```

all the textures are flipped properly, but the `SKPhysicsBody`s are unaffected. How do I flip the whole sprite with all the children and their `SKPhysicsBody`s properly?

Comment: Glad I found this, I've been struggling...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to create a physicsBody from a texture that is flipped horizontally is to create a flipped version of input image using an image editing software, such as Photoshop. An alternate way is to flip the original image using core graphics. Here's an example of how to do that:

```
func flippedTextureWithImageNamed(name:NSString) -> SKTexture
{
    let image = UIImage(named:name)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, image.size.width, image.size.height)
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, -1.0, -1.0)

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height), image.CGImage)

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return SKTexture(image: newImage)
}
```

Comment: It seems that there's also a Core Image filter that can flip the image. But this is enough for my purposes, thanks!

Comment: while flipping there in no smooth animation.. It suddenly flipping..  can we able to do that here..

Answer (score 2):

Scale is a visual property, it does not affects physics. To modify a node's shape you can only create and assign a new body with a new shape.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. So the question is, I guess, how to create a mirrored `SKPhysicsBody`. This seems to be the only way to flip a sprite with a physics body.